# Change uri name of a KFP artifact to .csv instead of "dataset"

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

When I output a KubeFlow Output[Dataset] that I know will be in a `CSV` format output URI is ending with the text `dataset`.

Is it possible to change the name of the URI to `dataset.csv` or to `training_data.csv`?
The full URI for the artifact is now `gs://<bucket-name>/<id>/<pipeline-name>+<id>/<script-name>+<id>/dataset`.

This is the code I am executing.

```
def extract_bq_to_dataset(
    bq_client_project_id: str,
    source_project_id: str,
    dataset_id: str,
    table_name: str,
    dataset: Output[Dataset],
    dataset_location: str = "EU",
    extract_job_config: dict = None,
    ):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    from google.cloud.exceptions import GoogleCloudError

    full_table_id = f"{source_project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_name}"
    table = bigquery.table.Table(table_ref=full_table_id)

    if extract_job_config is None:
        extract_job_config = {}
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig(**extract_job_config)

    client = bigquery.Client(project=bq_client_project_id, location=dataset_location)
    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        source=table,
        destination_uris=dataset.uri + ".csv",
        job_config=job_config,
        location=dataset_location,
    )
    print("Information about the artifact:")
    print("Name:", dataset.name)
    print("URI:", dataset.uri)
    print("Path:", dataset.path)
    print("Metadata:", dataset.metadata)

    try:
        result = extract_job.result()
    except GoogleCloudError as e:
        raise e
```

My solution now is to append `".csv"` to the `dataset.uri`. However, this breaks references later in the program since I can no longer reference the data by `train_data.path` but instead need to write `train_data.path+".csv"`. I would like to use the power to dynamically assign names, paths, and URI:s given by the KFP framework, and thus there is probably a better way to solve this than to manually add a `.csv` suffix as I'm doing now on the `extract_job = client.extract_table(...) line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more about KubeFlow pipelines, [pipelines/component-development](https://v0-7.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/sdk/component-development/), my understanding is that it's recommended to let the KubeFlow pipeline handle the data-passing between components.

Modifying the `URI` is not recommended since each component that reads output from the component which outputs an artifact with a modified URI has to adjust the artifact path to read the data.

To communicate that the output is in CSV format the artifact output name may instead be changed accordingly. E.g., change `dataset` to `csv_dataset` in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Users have control over all aspects of the output artifact. While KFP generates a unique GCS path for you and assigns that as the default for `dataset.uri`, you are free to override it with your own custom path that ends in `.csv`.

```py
# Add file format to generated path.
dataset.uri = dataset.uri + '.csv'

# Use a completely different path.
dataset.uri = 'gs://your-bucket/some/path.csv'
```

This new value for the artifact's URI will persist to downstream components that take the artifact as input regardless of if you are accessing the file via `.uri` (GCS path) or `.path` (local path).